# macbook, messed up my .profile and now no commands work like nano, rm, etc

Tags: macos, environment-variables, nano, .profile

I messed up a `.profile` and now I can't even get `nano` to work.

I was trying to add git to my environment variable whenever I start terminal, and I messed the command up obviously and no nothing works.

Not even the `ls` command works.

Where is `nano` so I can edit the file?

What should a standard `.profile` look like?

Comment: Next time you should back up sensitive files before you edit them ;)  I don't have a complete enough answer to throw in the answer section, but I would recommend creating a new user account and using that user's .profile as a "standard" .profile to see what you may have done wrong in your edits or at least restore what you had before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still be able to use the full path to run commands.
For example:

```
/bin/ls

/bin/nano
```

I'm not sure where `ls` is on a mac... it might be under /usr/bin/ls

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. My .profile file in my home directory looks like this:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Worth a shot i guess.

Comment: Glad it worked out (-:

Answer (score 0):

Where is this `.profile` you messed up? I have a `.bash_profile`, but no `.profile` file.

Comment: i created the following these directsion, but I put a ';' instead of a ':' in the line near the '$PATH' part. http://grasshopperpebbles.com/mac/installing-git-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: its in my 'home' folder, i.e.: cd ~

Answer (score 0):

Does the GUI still function (Finder, Desktop, Dock, etc.)? If so, Open the .profile file in TextEdit and replace the `;` with a `:` (you might have to turn on hidden files or type the name manually into the open file dialog)

If your GUI is no longer functioning, reboot the computer and hold `Command+S` as it reboots. This should dump you at a command line with root access. Use nano to fix your .profile file.